# calling multiple reveal modals reveal.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, reveal.js

I need to have multiple modal windows on the same page. Basically i intend on having a link to each team member which will then pop open their details in a modal box on click. I'm using reveal plugin by zurb. This is the example on the website.

html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
     <h1>Modal Title</h1>
     <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').reveal();
     });
```

Comment: what happens when you implement it? Is it not opening all the modals? If you have sample in jsfiddle, that would be good.

Comment: what is your motive? to reveal more than 1 modal at the same time or multiple instances to be opened with different button clicks.

Comment: To have different modals open with different information. So if I have joe, mary and ann, if the user clicks on joe his information pops up. The demo just works with ne modal on a page.

Comment: Well, the `myModal` div is a normal div, you can just add any content you want using jQuery (or even load remotely) before calling `.reveal()`. If you need to show multiple modals, you can `.clone()` the original one, change the id and then show as many as you like I can imagine. Can you show some of the code you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

I *just* did this exact thing. I expected it to be way more complicated than it was, so I kept looking in the wrong places. It’s all taken care of in the HTML!

First, duplicate the code you posted above for as many modals as you want to create, making the "div id" unique for each one (following your example above):

```
<div id="JOE" class="reveal-modal">
     <h1>Modal Title</h1>
     <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="MARY" class="reveal-modal">
     <h1>Modal Title</h1>
     <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="ANN" class="reveal-modal">
     <h1>Modal Title</h1>
     <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Next all you have to do create corresponding links to launch each one, making their unique "data-reveal-id" values match the IDs you created above, and place them wherever you need them in your layout:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="JOE" data-animation="fade">JOE</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="MARY" data-animation="fade">MARY</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="ANN" data-animation="fade">ANN</a>
```

Each link will only trigger the modal with the matching id tag.

Like I said, WAY easier than I expected it to be. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin for multiple windows.
minimize, maximize, move, close, overlay, menus, and more:

http://des.delestesoft.com:8080/?go=3